# Python generator for nested dictionary keys

Tags: python, iterator, generator

Let's say my dictionary is

```py
data = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': {
                'd': 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to code something like:

```py
for k,v in iterator(data):
    if some_conditions(k,v):
        v = some_value()
```

For all the keys of the dictionary, I want to check if the key, value pair matches some condition and update the value in the dictionary if necessary. The idea is that I don't have to keep track of the chain of keys to set the new value.

So, why not an iterator?

The idea seemed good, I would loop through all the keys of the dictionary and update the value on the fly if conditions were met. But I'm having some trouble implementing this, and the reason may be my lack of experience with iterators.

I attempted to code something but it fails and I don't understand why:

```
def gen(dic):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield v
            gen(v)

g = gen(data)
next(g)
```

The final data is more complex: some values may be lists having dictionaries as members and I will also have to deal with those dictionaries.

```py
data = {
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': [
                {
                    'd': 1,
                    'e': 2
                },
                1,
                {
                    'g': 1,
                    'h': 2
                },
                [
                    {
                        'i': {
                            'j': 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But if I can figure it out with a simple dictionary, I can then code for the larger case. I am open to different solutions that do not use iterators but remain clean and Pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
class Value:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v


def iterator(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for k, v in o.items():
            yield k, (val := Value(v))
            o[k] = val.v
            yield from iterator(v)
    if isinstance(o, list):
        for v in o:
            yield from iterator(v)


# return True if key is `d` and v is `1`
def some_condition(k, v):
    return k == "d" and v == 1


data = {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": 1}}}}

for k, val in iterator(data):
    if some_condition(k, val.v):
        val.v = 10

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 10}}}}
```

---

With the more complicated input:

```py
data = {"a": {"b": {"c": [{"d": 1, "e": 2}, 1, {"g": 1, "h": 2}, [{"i": {"j": 1}}]]}}}


def some_condition(k, v):
    return k == "h" and v == 2


for k, val in iterator(data):
    if some_condition(k, val.v):
        val.v = 9999

print(data)
```

Prints (note the value for the `h` key is changed):

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": [{"d": 1, "e": 2}, 1, {"g": 1, "h": 9999}, [{"i": {"j": 1}}]]}}}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, but still struggling to understand why yielding `val := Value(v))` and not simply `v` and why `o[k] = val.v`, and then right after you call again iterator using `v` (ie, you almost yield two times one after the other). I've tested in my more complex case and it works amazingly. I guess this is done like so to allow  the loop `for k, v in o.items()` to go on smoothly and me able to change the value of the key at the same time ? I'm still trying to understand the mechanics. Anyway, brilliant solution and very clean also.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive generator should do the job.  You would need it to return the nested dictionary along with the key and value in order for your calling code to change the key's value in the loop:

```
def dictIter(D,path=[]):
    content = enumerate(D) if isinstance(D,list) else D.items() 
    for k,v in content:
        if isinstance(v,(dict,list)):
            yield from dictIter(v,path+[k])
        else:
            yield D,path,k,v
```

output:

```
data = {'a': {'b': {'c': [{'d': 1, 'e': 2}, 1, {'g': 1, 'h': 2}, [{'i': {'j': 1}}]]}}}

for d,parents,key,value in dictIter(data):
    if key == "h":
        d[key] = value + 20
    if value == 1:
        d[key] = value + 100

print(data)
{'a': {'b': {'c': [{'d': 101, 'e': 2}, 101, {'g': 101, 'h': 22}, [{'i': {'j': 101}}]]}}}
```

*Note that I added the path (parents) to the output, you can remove that part of the code if you don't need it*

Answer (score -1):

You can try this recursive approach:

```
def update_nested_dict(dic):
for k, v in dic.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        update_nested_dict(v)
    elif isinstance(v, list):
        for item in v:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                update_nested_dict(item)
    else:
        if some_conditions(k, v):
            dic[k] = some_value()
```

## Example usage

```
data = {'a': {'b': {'c': [{'d': 1, 'e': 2}, 1, {'g': 1, 'h': 2}, [{'i': {'j': 1}}]]}}}
update_nested_dict(data)
print(data)
```

Comment: Please fix your code block. As written, this generates an `IndentationError`.